# Uniquify list and get indices of matching elements

Tags: python

I have a list, say `[a, b, c, a, a, b]`. I want as output to get a list of indices of the matching elements. for this example it would then be `[[0, 3, 4], [1, 5]]`.

The lists will be small so performance or memory use is not of importance. is there already a built-in function for lists or either for numpy/pandas that can do this?

Comment: Not related to getting an answer to your question, just out of my own curiousity: I don't understand why the `c` element is not present in the result. Why is the outcome not `[[0, 3, 4], [1, 5], [2]]`?

Comment: c isn't present because it appears only once and hence I don't care about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b']
d = defaultdict(list)
for i,x in enumerate(items):
    d[x].append(i)
matches = [v for v in d.values() if len(v)>1]
print(matches) #[[0, 3, 4], [1, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b']

idxs = [[idx for idx, _ in grp] for _, grp in groupby( sorted(enumerate(items), key=itemgetter(1)), itemgetter(1))]
idxs = [x for x in idxs if len(x)>1]
idxs # = [[0, 3, 4], [1, 5]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not the place for such question but helping others is a must.

```
def uniquify(l:list):
    unique_elements=[]
    for el in l:
        if el not in unique_elements:unique_elements.append(el)
    output=[]
    for element in unique_elements :
        output.append([i for i in range(len(l)) if l[i]==element])
    return output
```